# Having trouble updating code from polars 0.28 to 0.31

Tags: rust, rust-polars

Hi I am having trouble updating code from polars 0.28 to 0.31.
There are a few calls I use and the problems are not listed in the breaking changes.
As there are a few problems to keep the question simple I will only post the first one here and see if that helps with the others.

The first is trying to update the following code.
The data frame is a i32 sensor_id a datetime ts and a floating point value column.

```
 df = df.upsample(&["sensor_id"],
                    "ts", 
                    polars::time::Duration::parse(period),
                    polars::time::Duration::parse("0m")).unwrap();
```

I get

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidOperation(ErrString("argument in operation 'upsample' is not explicitly sorted\n\n- If your data is ALREADY sorted, set the sorted flag with: '.set_sorted()'.\n- If your data is NOT sorted, sort the 'expr/series/column' first.\n    "))', /home/glenn/bmos/libbmos/src/lib.rs:4638:58
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I don't see a set_sorted() method in the docs like the error suggests only set_sorted_flag for expr
and no idea how to use it.

I have tried something like

```
df = df.upsample(&[col("sensor_id").set_sorted_flag(polars::series::IsSorted::Ascending)],
                    "ts", 
                    polars::time::Duration::parse(period),
                    polars::time::Duration::parse("0m")).unwrap();
```

but that gives

```
the trait bound `polars::prelude::Expr: AsRef<str>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `polars::prelude::IntoVec<T>`:
  <Vec<T> as polars::prelude::IntoVec<T>>
  <bool as polars::prelude::IntoVec<bool>>
required for `&polars::prelude::Expr` to implement `AsRef<str>`
required for `&[polars::prelude::Expr; 1]` to implement `polars::prelude::IntoVec<std::string::String>`
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time column must be sorted as stated [here](https://docs.rs/polars/0.31.1/polars/prelude/trait.PolarsUpsample.html#tymethod.upsample). There are several options:

#### 1. Sort

You can just do the sort:

```rust
let df = df.sort(["ts"], false, true).unwrap();
```

#### 2. set_sorted_flag with LazyFrame

You can use the `set_sorted_flag` on an expression like this:

```rust
let df = df
    .lazy()
    .with_column(col("ts").set_sorted_flag(IsSorted::Ascending))
    .collect()
    .unwrap()
    .upsample(
        &["sensor_id"],
        "ts",
        polars::time::Duration::parse("1d"),
        polars::time::Duration::parse("0m"),
    )
    .unwrap();
```

#### 3. set_sorted_flag on existing DataFrame

There is another solution without `LazyFrame` but you have to use unsafe (at least I cannot find another solution):

```rust
unsafe {
    let columns = df.get_columns_mut();
    // assuming ts is the first column
    columns[0].set_sorted_flag(IsSorted::Ascending);
}
```

#### 4. set_sorted_flag before creating DataFrame

When you create the `DataFrame` with existing `Series` columns, you can set the flag before creating the `DataFrame`:

```rust
let mut ts = Series::new("ts", <data>);
ts.set_sorted_flag(IsSorted::Ascending);
let df = DataFrame::new(vec![ts, <other columns>]).unwrap();
```

#### Warning

When using `set_sorted_flag` the column must be sorted. Use with care. See [here](https://docs.rs/polars/0.31.1/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.set_sorted_flag).

Comment: Thanks 
As upsample does not work on a lazy frame I did method 3 with the unsafe (Yuck)

Comment: @GlennPierce You are right. Upsample only works on a DataFrame, not LazyFrame. But the `.collect().unwrap()` in option 2 converts it back to DataFrame. So it should work for you. Keep in mind that you have to enable the lazy feature in your Cargo.toml: `polars = { version = "0.31", features = ["lazy"] }`